# Groovy call field

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to put into the field an object that supports a call operation, and then to call him. I can do it without intermediate reading fields in a variable?
My attempt looks like this:

```
class CallableObjectDynamic {
    def call() {
        return "5"
    }
}


class MyClassDynamic {
    CallableObjectDynamic field = new CallableObjectDynamic()
}

class GroovyRunnerDynamic {
    static String make(int arg1) {
        MyClassDynamic x = new MyClassDynamic()
        return x.field()
    }
}
```

​
But I receive `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`.

What can you do? Or can anyone give a proof where it's written that we can't call the field?

Comment: you have to return `42` in examples

Comment: do you want to use the implicit `call` method?

Comment: @injecteer yes, I want only implicit call

Comment: Change `return x.field()` to `return (x.field)()`. Membership has lower precedence than function invocation.

Comment: J Di Or Eximen, Have you considered accepting one of these two answers?

Answer (score 1):

Membership (`.`) has lower order of precedence than function/method/call invocation (`()`). Thus this line:

```
        return x.field()
```

is interpreted as "invoke the '`field`' method on the '`x`' object".

To get Groovy to parse the code as you desire, the minimal change would be to regroup using parentheses, as follows:

```
        return (x.field)()
```

which is (ultimately) interpreted as "invoke the '`call`' method on the '`field`' object member of the '`x`' object", as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial issue. Not required to have parenthesis for `field`.

Change from:

```
return x.field()
```

To:

```
return x.field
```

If you want to execute `call` method further, then use below code snippet. 
Note that `static` method return type is changed.

```groovy
class CallableObjectDynamic {
    def call() {
        return "5"
    }
}


class MyClassDynamic {
    CallableObjectDynamic field = new CallableObjectDynamic()
}

class GroovyRunnerDynamic {
    static def make(int arg1) {
        MyClassDynamic x = new MyClassDynamic()
        return x.field
    }
}


​GroovyRunnerDynamic.make(1)​.call()​
```

Output would be : 5
Not sure why argument to `make` method is done here, seems to be not used in the above code.

Alternatively, you can change

```
class GroovyRunnerDynamic {
    static def make(int arg1) {
        MyClassDynamic x = new MyClassDynamic()
        return x.field.call()
    }
}

​GroovyRunnerDynamic.make(1)
```

**EDIT: Based on OP's implicit call.**
Not really sure how it is working, but the below does implicit call. Just assign `x.field` to a variable and just add parenthesis for that as shown below.

```
class GroovyRunnerDynamic {
    static String make(int arg1) {
        MyClassDynamic x = new MyClassDynamic()
        def fun = x.field
        fun()
    }
}
GroovyRunnerDynamic.make(1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not focused, but it is important to realize that is an implicit call to and return its result.

Comment: @JDiOrEximen, please see if the edited answer helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works because we read into the variable ```fun``` object with type ```CallableObjectDynamic```. After calling the ```fun()``` we make an implicit call of operator ```call```.

Comment: The only difference between this case which I was expecting from my example, we prompt the Groovy what's here now will be reading the field, and here the method call. I'm doing compiler research, and it seemed to me that this is a bug that we cannot make a call to the field. I thought that I did not know some of the subtleties of the language Groovy. Now it seems that what you suggested is the only way to do implicit invocation

Comment: @JDiOrEximen, if you think this is the best solution, appreciate if this can accepted as answer & up vote for helpful answers.